# is there any way i can make jquery work with node.io?

Tags: jquery, node.js

Node.js noob. I am using node.io to scrape websites but I would love to use jquery within node.io. The [$ object](https://github.com/chriso/node.io/wiki/API---CSS-Selectors-and-Traversal-methods) provided by node.io doesn't provide much flexibility.

```
var nodeio = require('node.io'), options = {timeout: 10},
    jQuery = require('jquery');

exports.job = new nodeio.Job(options, {
    input: ['hello', 'foobar', 'weather'],
    run: function (keyword) {
        this.getHtml('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(keyword), function (err, $) {

            // SOMEHOW CREATE THE JQUERY OBJECT USING $

            var results = $('#resultStats').text.toLowerCase();
            this.emit(keyword + ' has ' + results);
        });
    }
});
```

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

I din't notice that node.io had an option to use jquery with the `jsdom:true` option. It doesn't work even when I use this option, I always get a timeout error OR $ is undefined error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured out the problem.

node.io has an option to use jquery, you need to pass this option `jsdom:true`. The version of node.io (0.3.0) I was using had a bug in it which always returned a timeout.

```
  // lib/node.io/dom.js
  window.onload = function() {
    callback.apply(self, [null, $, data, headers, response]);
  }
```

Now this is fixed in node.io version 0.3.1

Thank you all for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [**jsdom**](http://jsdom.org/) - a module that mimics the DOM in JS, allowing you to use any JS library designed for the browser.

This blog post explains how to combine it with jQuery: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs.

Comment: i know about jsdom, i specifically needed help with assigning the $ window object of node.io to a jquery or jsdom object as shown above, so that I can use jquery. Sorry, but your answer doesn't help!

Comment: @Madhusudhan, you can replace `$` with anything you want. The point is that jQuery won't work without a full emulation of the browser DOM, which is why you need jsdom. You can read the blog post I linked to for help on doing that.

Comment: Actually I din't see this, node.io has an option for using jquery. The default option is jsdom:false, when you pass true, you get the jquery object in $. Not sure why, its throwing an error saying $ is undefined when i use jsdom:true

Answer (score 1):

You might just look at using spider by mikeal --- it supports this use case out of the box, and is built for scraping.

https://github.com/mikeal/spider

Example:

```
var spider = require('../main');

spider()
.route('www.nytimes.com', '/pages/dining/index.html', function (window, $) {
  $('a').spider();
})
.route('travel.nytimes.com', '*', function (window, $) {
  $('a').spider();
  if (this.fromCache) return;

  var article = { title: $('nyt_headline').text(), articleBody: '', photos: [] }
  article.body = '' 
  $('div.articleBody').each(function () {
    article.body += this.outerHTML;
  })
  $('div#abColumn img').each(function () {
    var p = $(this).attr('src');
    if (p.indexOf('ADS') === -1) {
      article.photos.push(p);
    }
  })
  // console.log(article);
})
.route('dinersjournal.blogs.nytimes.com', '*', function (window, $) {
  var article = {title: $('h1.entry-title').text()}
  // console.log($('div.entry-content').html())
})
.get('http://www.nytimes.com/pages/dining/index.html')
.log('info')
;
```

Also, if you're intent on node.io -- I think node.io passes data as an optional parameter:

```
io.getHTML('someurl', function(err, junk, data){
    jsdom.env({
      html: data,
      scripts : [
        'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
      ]
    }, function(err, window) {
          var $ = window.jQuery;
          // use jquery here
   });
});
```